Python obtain latest email from a sender using win32com.client
Trying to obtain the last email sent by a sender in outlook so I can download an attachment.
The issue I have is that the date the email was sent is not consistently sent every day so using something like the below won't work.
CurrentDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
CurrentDateTime = CurrentDateTime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
messages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] > '" + CurrentDateTime +"'")

The below code gives me the correct list but Only want to get the attachment from the latest email.
import win32com.client as client

ol_app = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = ol_app.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
for message in messages:
    if message.SenderEmailAddress == 'test@test.com':
        print(message.Subject)

I'm planning to use 'for attachment in message.Attachments:'once i have isolated the the last email.

I have a function from a script I made which basically does what you want to do, see if you get an idea from there:

def download_latest_email_attachment(download_folder):
    """Download the latest email attachment that starts with 'Monitoreo Colateral' and ends with '.xlsx'."""
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)  # "6" refers to the inbox
    messages = inbox.Items
    messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)

    for message in messages:
        if message.Attachments.Count > 0:
            for attachment in message.Attachments:
                if attachment.FileName.startswith("Monitoreo Colateral") and attachment.FileName.endswith(".xlsx"):
                    attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(download_folder, attachment.FileName))
                    print(f"Downloaded attachment: {attachment.FileName}")
                    return os.path.join(download_folder, attachment.FileName)
    print("No attachment found.")
    return None


This works perfectly, thank you.

You can achieve this by sorting the messages based on their ReceivedTime in descending order and then selecting the first message, which will be the latest email.
import win32com.client as client

ol_app = client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox = ol_app.GetDefaultFolder(6)
messages = inbox.Items
messages.Sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)  # Sort messages by ReceivedTime in descending order
latest_message = None

for message in messages:
    if message.SenderEmailAddress == 'test@test.com':
        latest_message = message
        break  # Exit the loop after finding the latest message

if latest_message:
    print(latest_message.Subject)
    # Now you can iterate over the attachments in the latest message
    for attachment in latest_message.Attachments:
        # Download the attachment here
        pass
else:
    print("No email found from the specified sender.")

